# Глупая ошибка в ref/out

Tags: c#

Выдает сразу две ошибки: `}expected` и `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected`, по отношению к строке с WriteLine'ом и самой последней скобкой, соответственно.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "ref/out";
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            int one = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int two;
            int one1 = one;
            variablesChange(ref one, out two);
            Console.WriteLine("You've set variable as "+one1+", but then changed it to "+one+". The second one is "+two);

            public static void variablesChange (ref int a, out int b)
            {
                a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы явно перемудрили (или недомудрили) со скобками. Перенесите закрывающую фигурную скобку, стоящую после метода variablesChange  и поставьте ее после WriteLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "ref/out";
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int one = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int two;
        int one1 = one;
        variablesChange(ref one, out two);
        Console.WriteLine("You've set variable as "+one1+", but then changed it to "+one+". The second one is "+two);
    }

    public static void variablesChange (ref int a, out int b)
    {
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Функция не должна находиться в другой функции.